# Keycloak custom Authenticator for successfull password reset

Tags: keycloak

Keycloak provides "Forgot Password" functionality. It is working. By clicking this, I entered email and a link is sent to my email. On clicking the link I can reset my password.

After successful password reset, i want to update the password in some other Application too.

My question is, Is it possible to call another service after Successfull password reset? (Not with EventListenerProvider. )
How can we write Custom Authenticator for successfull password reset.